# How to use Nauty and Traces to determine is two graph isomorpfic?

Tags: isomorphism

i have two graph in format p edge, some like this

```
p edge 180 864
e 1 3
e 1 9
e 1 119
e 1 126
e 1 127
e 1 177
e 2 9
```

how to run dreadnaut\nauty  to determine if two graph is isomorphic?

i am asked chatGPT that provided this answer

```
dreadnaut < graph1.txt > graph1.can
dreadnaut < graph2.txt > graph2.can

nauty graph1.can graph2.can
```

but it diddnot works.

i have two graph in format p edge, some like this

```
p edge 180 864
e 1 3
e 1 9
e 1 119
e 1 126
e 1 127
e 1 177
e 2 9
```

how to run dreadnaut\nauty  to determine if two graph is isomorphic?

i am asked chatGPT that provided this answer

```
dreadnaut < graph1.txt > graph1.can
dreadnaut < graph2.txt > graph2.can

nauty graph1.can graph2.can
```

but it diddnot works.